# What is the difference between HasMaxLength(50) and HasColumnType("nvarchar(50)")?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I'm trying to understand the difference between two ways of limiting size of nvarchar in Entity Framework.

First one is:
`

```
 entity.Property(e => e.TurbineSerialNumber)
                      .HasColumnName("TurbineSerialNumber")
                      .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
                      .HasMaxLength(50)
                      .IsRequired(true);
```

`
And second one is:

```
 entity.Property(e => e.TurbineSerialNumber)
                      .HasColumnName("TurbineSerialNumber")
                      .HasColumnType("nvarchar(50)")
                      .IsRequired(true);
```

What is the difference between them? And can it somehow affect my code in either positive or negative way?

I've tried to find it myself, but unfortunately I've not found the clear difference.

Comment: When you generate the migration, is the code on the generated file the same?

Comment: @Camadas I was not trying to generate the file, the code you can see here is added manually

Comment: I know that, but from what I see in there, is just 2 ways of doing the same thing, that's why I asked if there was any diference when you generate the migration

Comment: The HasMaxLength might be automatically supported as a UI constraint, depending on what technology you're using for a user interface. The column type probably doesn't register as a UI constraint, but you can test your UI to see if either one is supported.